# is there any way to check if class is persistable

Tags: jpa

Is there any way in JPA to check pragmatically if a class is *persistent* (annotated with *@Entity*) ?

Comment: If you try to persist a class that isn't backed by JPA you'll get a run-time exception.  What specifically were you looking for/trying to mitigate against?

Comment: You might want to use something like `getClass().getAnnotations()` to query some object for its annotations.

Comment: Why the downvote? Can people please explain what's wrong when they give downvotes so people know what to improve in the future

Comment: @Makoto in our framework that uses command pattern, the commands can be persisted to the DB or not. To control that we have a flag isPersistent() on each command. I would like to remove that flag and base our logic around Entity annotation (if it's present persist the command, if not then don't...)

Comment: probably question would be better "class is persistable?". Or do You think about class instance aka object???

Comment: and what if it is specified in `orm.xml` ? without annotations ... still "persistent"

Comment: @DN1 I'm not considering the case where it's defined in orm.xml, since we don't use it, but I guess you could parse the xml file and get that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether it the class has the `Entity` annotation :

```
if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)){
   //
}
```

The `Entity` may be present but the class may not be mapped by your JPA implementation for different reasons.

So here is a way to check whether the `EntityManagerFactory` has mapped it :

```
EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().entity(clazz);
```

It throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if it is not an entity mapped by the EntityManagerFactory.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it, if it is annotated with @Entity not an XML configuration. 
And you have two options:

- At run-time using [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-)
- At compile-time using [annotation preprocessor](http://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder), this is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Class<?> cls = YourClassName.class;
     System.out.println("is entity annotated? "+cls.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class));
}
```

Comment: can some before downvoting this tell what's the issue with this code?

Comment: I guess the reason was, that the code wasn't formatted as code. However, this answer is useful and i agree it would be better if people pointed this out before clicking on the downvote

Comment: You have no description. Is this the solution, or some random code? How does it solve the issue, what did you change from the OP's code. Needs moar explanation and info ;)

Comment: Yes. If we want to know the the class is annotated with @Entity. The same way want to know if a class is annotated with talbe, just keep Table.class